# Initial values for Heston Model calibration

Tags: monte-carlo, matlab, calibration, heston

I'm doing a Heston model in Matlab using simple Monte Carlo simulations (5.000 paths and 2 steps per day, simulating 360 days). When I try to calibrate the Heston parameters using fminsearch it takes a lot of time and initial values almost doesn't change, so I guess there are a lot local minimization points. So is there any algorithm to obtain good initial values?

Kind regards,
Oliver.

Comment: try searching adjoint calibration Heston

Comment: I think fmincon (Find minimum of constrained nonlinear multivariable function) better than fminsearch

Comment: Hi, here is a great reference for anything you might encounter while calibrating Heston model "The Heston Model and its Extensions in Matlab and C#" by F.D.Rouah.